# Read_CSV() with a non-constant file location

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Quick question here I'd like to use pandas read_csv to bring in a file for my python script but it is a daily drop and both the filename and file location changes each day...

My first thought is to get around this by prompting the user for the path?  Or is there a more elegant solution that can be coded?

The filepath (with name) is something like this:

DailyDownload>20180301>[randomtags]_YEH.csv

Comment: read_csv takes a variable for the path, so there is no debate - yes, read_csv works with a non-constant file location.  I suggest you reframe your question to something along the lines of: "How do I find the path of a file whose name and directory changes each day?"  Give better details about how the name and location change every day, and if there's anything else in its directory to contend with.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `sorted(glob.glob("DailyDownload/*/*_YEH.csv"))[-1]` will return one file from the most recent day's downloads. This might work for you if you are certain that only one file per day will be downloaded.

A better solution might be to grab *all* the files (`glob.glob("DailyDownload/*/*_YEH.csv"`) and then somehow mark them as you process them. Perhaps store the list of processed files in a database? Or delete each file as you complete the processing?